# MySQL Query returns unexpected results

Tags: mysql

My Preneed table only contains 3 rows;

```
Preneed_tb
+----+-----------+----------+---------+----------+
| id | fullname  | plannum  | remarks | pre_type |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+----------+
|  1 | jAMES YAP | SDF12321 | FB      | HIP      |
|  2 | asdasdas  | 213      | 1gb     | CEA      |
|  3 | gdaae     | 12fvs    | dfcv    | CEA      |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+----------+
```

The MySQL Query returns duplicate rows with the same data:

```
select    fullname as 'FullName', 
          plannum as 'Plan_Number', 
          remarks as 'Remarks', 
          pre_type as 'Pre_Need_Type', 
          concat(x.id,'-PRENEED') as 'Identification' 
from      preneed_tb as x
left join filelocation 
on        filelocation.f_id = x.id
left join (select   max(f_logs.id),
                    f_id, 
                    log_status 
           from     f_logs 
           group by f_id) as y 
on         y.f_id = x.id
WHERE      concat(f_location,' ') like 'SFDSF %' 
and        concat(y.log_status, ' ') like 'IN STORA%'
```

I use x.id because i got 
Unknown column 'preneed_tb.id' in 'field list' when i tried to use preneed_tb

Sample Result:

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
| FullName  | Plan_Number | Remarks | Pre_Need_Type | Identification |
+-----------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
| jAMES YAP | SDF12321    | FB      | HIP           | 1-PRENEED      |
| jAMES YAP | SDF12321    | FB      | HIP           | 1-PRENEED      |
| jAMES YAP | SDF12321    | FB      | HIP           | 1-PRENEED      |
+-----------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
```

And then when i use this query, it return the expected result:

```
 select   fullName,
          Plan_Number,
          Remarks, 
          Pre_Need_Type, 
          Identification 
    from     (select fullname as 'FullName', 
                      plannum as 'Plan_Number', 
                     remarks as 'Remarks', 
                     pre_type as 'Pre_Need_Type', 
                     concat(preneed_tb.id,'-PRENEED') as 'Identification' 
              from   preneed_tb) as x
left join filelocation 
on filelocation.f_id = x.identification
left join (select   max(f_logs.id),
                        f_id, 
                        log_status 
               from     f_logs 
               group by f_id) as y 
    on         y.f_id = x.identification
    WHERE      concat(f_location,' ') like 'SFDSF %' 
    and        concat(y.log_status, ' ') like 'IN STORA%'
```

Sample Result:

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
| FullName  | Plan_Number | Remarks | Pre_Need_Type | Identification |
+-----------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
| jAMES YAP | SDF12321    | FB      | HIP           | 1-PRENEED      |
+-----------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
```

Can anyone explain this to me? I am very confused because it returns duplicate entry but i only have one match in my table

Answer (score 0):

You want remove duplicated  rows use distinct clause

```
  select distinct 
     fullname as 'FullName'
    , plannum as 'Plan_Number'
    , remarks as 'Remarks'
    , pre_type as 'Pre_Need_Type'
    , concat(preneed_tb.id,'-PRENEED') as 'Identification' 
  from preneed_tb as x
  left join filelocation on filelocation.f_id = x.id
  left join (select max(f_logs.id),f_id, log_status 
                from f_logs group by f_id) as y on y.f_id = x.id
  WHERE concat(f_location,' ') like 'SFDSF %' 
  and concat(y.log_status, ' ') like 'IN STORA%'"
```

Comment: Actually, there is no duplicate entry in my database, the query just return it 3 times, but i only have 1 data in my database, that is why i am confused

Comment: you have 3  result because is joined  with some others row with 3 values .. related  to you r single values ..

Answer (score 0):

You have inverted ON conditions ,in the first one

```
filelocation.f_id = x.id
```

where x = preneed_tb

In the second you have

```
filelocation.f_id = x.identification
```

where x =preneed_tb